# TensorFlow conv2d not converging to expected result

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

As part of my quest to fully understand tensorflow, I've designed simple experiments to verify my understanding of what's going on.

I'm trying to train a convnet to produce a scaled version of the input where the system looks something like this:

[image]

The training data are vectors I created in MATLAB of `shape=[1, 1, n, 1]` that look like this:

```
input  =         [a, a, a, ..., a]
output =  0.25 * [a, a, a, ..., a]
```

and the filter kernel I'm training, `W` is of `shape=[1, 1, 1, 1]`

I would imagine that the value of `W` should train to 0.25, but it trains to 0.189. Similarly, when I create inputs and outputs with an initial scale factor of 0.5, the system trains to 0.378.

I am so confused. **Why would the filter train to two-thirds of its expected value**?

**Here's my code**:
I/O generation (MATLAB)

```
data = [];
numPts = 500;
for indx = 0:19999
    data(end+1).x = rand(1,1).*ones(1,numPts);
    data(end).y = .25 * data(end).x;
end
```

Model and Training (python tensorflow)
[I've removed my input function to reduce the size of the post, but I'm sure it's working]

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('max_steps', 50000,"""Number of batches to run.""")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('num_samples', 500,"""Samples per vect.""")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('filter_size', 1,"""Size of filter.""")

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()

    d1, d2 = inputs()

    # Placeholders
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="X")
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 1, FLAGS.num_samples, 1), name="Y")

    # TRAINABLE FILTER KERNEL
    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, FLAGS.filter_size, 1, 1]), dtype=tf.float32)

    # MODEL
    x = tf.reshape(X, shape=[1, 1, FLAGS.num_samples, 1])
    y_predicted = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

    # LOSS AND STUFF
    Y = tf.reshape(Y, shape=[1, 1, FLAGS.num_samples])
    y_p = tf.reshape(y_predicted, shape=[1, 1, FLAGS.num_samples])

    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=Y, predictions=y_p)

    opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)

    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                       tf.local_variables_initializer())

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        sess.run(init_op)

        tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=tf.train.Coordinator())

        loss_vals, w_vals = [], [] # for storage

        for n in range(0, FLAGS.max_steps):
            x_data = sess.run(d1)
            y_data = sess.run(d2)

            sess.run(opt, feed_dict={
                             X: x_data,
                             Y: y_data
                         })

            # DISPLAY PROGRESS
            if n % 500 == 0:
                print(n)

            # STORE LOSS AND FILTER
            if n % 100 == 0:
                w_vals.append(sess.run([W]))
                loss_vals.append(
                    sess.run(loss, feed_dict={
                        X: x_data,
                        Y: y_data
                    }))

        # SAVE TO MATLAB
        sio.savemat('./params.mat', {'loss': loss_vals, 'w': w_vals})
```

**Things I've done**

1. I've verified that if you conv2d something with a value of 0.25, it scales it by 0.25
2. I've tried lots of losses. `huber_loss`, `absolute_difference`, `tf.square(Y - y_p)`. Always ~2/3 too low.
3. I've played with the optimizer. `AdamOptimizer`, `GradientDescentOptimizer`. Changed the learning rate.  Always ~2/3 too low.
4. Made some pretty pictures of this filter weight converging on 0.189 [(absolute_difference and mean_squared_error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JrV9.jpg). Interestingly when you zoom in on the data, tensorflow seems to be repeating it's choice of weight values every 5000 steps; but that's a story for a different day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem for me. I've changed the input from `matlab` to `python.numpy`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('max_steps', 50000, "Number of batches to run.""")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('num_samples', 500, "Samples per vect.""")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('filter_size', 1, "Size of filter.""")

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()

    # Placeholders
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="X")
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 1, FLAGS.num_samples, 1), name="Y")

    # TRAINABLE FILTER KERNEL
    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, FLAGS.filter_size, 1, 1]), dtype=tf.float32)

    # MODEL
    x = tf.reshape(X, shape=[1, 1, FLAGS.num_samples, 1])
    y_predicted = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

    # LOSS AND STUFF
    y = tf.reshape(Y, shape=[1, 1, FLAGS.num_samples])
    y_p = tf.reshape(y_predicted, shape=[1, 1, FLAGS.num_samples])

    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y, predictions=y_p)

    opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)

    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                       tf.local_variables_initializer())

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        sess.run(init_op)

        tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=tf.train.Coordinator())

        loss_vals, w_vals = [], [] # for storage

        for n in range(0, FLAGS.max_steps):
            x_data = np.random.normal(size=(1, 1, FLAGS.num_samples, 1))
            y_data = x_data * 0.25

            sess.run(opt, feed_dict={
                             X: x_data,
                             Y: y_data
                         })

            # STORE LOSS AND FILTER
            if n % 100 == 0:
                w_vals.append(sess.run([W]))
                loss_vals.append(
                    sess.run(loss, feed_dict={
                        X: x_data,
                        Y: y_data
                    }))

            # DISPLAY PROGRESS
            if n % 500 == 0:
                print n, loss_vals[-1], w_vals[-1]
```

and the output is like this:

```
0 0.0106585 [array([[[[ 0.14452107]]]], dtype=float32)]
500 0.00148794 [array([[[[ 0.21119362]]]], dtype=float32)]
1000 0.000211823 [array([[[[ 0.23576953]]]], dtype=float32)]
1500 2.60087e-05 [array([[[[ 0.24478287]]]], dtype=float32)]
2000 3.46493e-06 [array([[[[ 0.24807557]]]], dtype=float32)]
2500 5.06054e-07 [array([[[[ 0.2492941]]]], dtype=float32)]
3000 6.88539e-08 [array([[[[ 0.24974038]]]], dtype=float32)]
3500 8.94391e-09 [array([[[[ 0.2499048]]]], dtype=float32)]
4000 1.31581e-09 [array([[[[ 0.24996498]]]], dtype=float32)]
4500 1.67827e-10 [array([[[[ 0.24998713]]]], dtype=float32)]
5000 2.12909e-11 [array([[[[ 0.24999554]]]], dtype=float32)]
```

Maybe you should check your input of matlab data.

Comment: Thanks! The input data shape was off. Using a shape of `shape=[1, 1, FLAGS.num_samples]` for X and Y, and a shape of `shape=[FLAGS.num_samples, 1, 1, 1]` cleared everything up.